# PHP значение из input с onclock

Tags: php, html

Есть два поля от календаря начальная и текущая дата инпутовские, где дата выбирается. Никак не могу понять как вытащить значение после выбора

```
<form method="post" 
<h3>Кликните на поле ввода даты для вызова календаря:</h3>
 с <input id="d1" type="text" value="день-месяц-год" 
onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"  data- 
yearfrom="-80" data-yearto="5">
по <input name="d2" type="text" value="день-месяц-год" 
onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)" data- 
yearto="5">
<input  type="submit" name="select1"  form="myform" value="вывести из БД"/>

</p>

</form>
```

пробовал по id или name через POST но все равно не получается с обычным инпутом все нормально постом выгребается

Comment: не видно формы вашей....если приведенный код находится в форме, то ищите значение `input`а в файлике, который прописан в `action` под переменной `$_POST["d1"]` если `method = "post"`

Comment: У d1 нет атрибута name.

Comment: вот пробовал...и с атрибутом name....ничего..пробую с обычным импутом который без выбора даты онкликом в календаре, там все работает(...а тут $_POST['d2'] ни катит

Answer (score 0):

Исправил код: добавил закрывающую скобку тега form и id формы который потом указал на кнопке

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
   <h3>Click on the date entry field to call the calendar.:</h3>
   <p>
        from the <input name="d1" id="d1" type="text"
                value="day month Year"
                onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
                onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
                data-yearfrom="-80"
                data-yearto="5"/>

        to the <input name="d2" id="d2" type="text"
              value="day month Year"
              onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
              onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
              data-yearto="5"/>

       <input type="submit" name="select1" form="myform" value="data from bd"/>
  </p>
</form>
```